# sort data from post request into a json predefined schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sorting

I am trying from a post request with info to sort them "automatically".

- Each category is defined by a number (0 -> 1 -> ....)
- There is for each category 1 title defined by its number ex: "0": "Are planes flying?"
- 5 questions that go from A to E that contain the value q in its name ex: "0-qA": "maybe"
- And answers for each category  ex: "0-A": "on" but if 0-B has not been checked then there will be nothing.

This is what come out of req.body:

```json
{
  '0': 'Are planes flying ?',
  '1': 'Are tomatoes flying ?',
  title: 'What flies',
  '0-qA': 'Maybe,
  '0-A': 'on'
  '0-qB': 'Yes',
  '0-qC': 'No',
  '0-C': 'on',
  '0-qD': 'Ask to Patrick',
  '0-D': 'on',
  '0-qE': 'Answer C',
  '1-qA': 'Maybe no',
  '1-qB': 'Yes',
  '1-qC': 'No',
  '1-C': 'on',
  '1-qD': 'Do not ask me',
  '1-D': 'on',
  '1-qE': 'Answer A',
  '1-E': 'on'
  'num': '1' //equal to how many questions I have
}
```

then i want to "sort" them to look like this:

```json
{
"title": "What flies",
"questions": [
                {
                    "question": "Are planes flying ?",
                    "choix": [
                        {
                            "id": "A",
                            "text": "Maybe"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "B",
                            "text": "Yes"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "C",
                            "text": "No"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "D",
                            "text": "Ask to patrick"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "E",
                            "text": "Answer C"
                        }
                    ],
                    "answers": [
                        "0-A",
                        "0-C",
                        "0-D"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "question": "Are tomatoes flying ?",
                    "choix": [
                        {
                            "id": "A",
                            "text": "Maybe no"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "B",
                            "text": "Yes"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "C",
                            "text": "No"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "D",
                            "text": "Don't ask me"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "E",
                            "text": "Answer A"
                        }
                    ],
                    "answers": [
                        "1-C",
                        "1-D",
                        "1-E"
                    ]
                },
              ]
}
```

I've tried by using num with `for(i in num)` but it came to nothing.
Thank you in advance for any answers you can bring me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys of the data, looping over values from `0` to `data['num']` and matching choices and answers based on the patterns of the keys (choices starting with a number then `-q` and answers with a number followed by `-` and a letter which is not `q`:

```js
const data = {
  '0': 'Are planes flying ?',
  '1': 'Are tomatoes flying ?',
  'title': 'What flies',
  '0-qA': 'Maybe',
  '0-A': 'on',
  '0-qB': 'Yes',
  '0-qC': 'No',
  '0-C': 'on',
  '0-qD': 'Ask to Patrick',
  '0-D': 'on',
  '0-qE': 'Answer C',
  '1-qA': 'Maybe no',
  '1-qB': 'Yes',
  '1-qC': 'No',
  '1-C': 'on',
  '1-qD': 'Do not ask me',
  '1-D': 'on',
  '1-qE': 'Answer A',
  '1-E': 'on',
  'num': '1' //equal to how many questions I have
};

let result = {
  'title': data['title'],
  'questions': []
};

for (let i = 0; i <= parseInt(data['num']); i++) {
  let key = i + '';
  let question = {
    'question': data[key],
    'choix': Object.keys(data)
      .filter(k => k.startsWith(`${key}-q`))
      .map(k => ({
        id: k.split('q')[1],
        text: data[k]
      })),
    'answers': Object.keys(data)
      .filter(k => k.match(new RegExp(`${key}-[^q]\$`)))
  };
  result['questions'].push(question);
}

console.log(result)
```